# Magento 2 | Troubles changing CSS class attribute value.

Tags: magento-2.1, css, less

I am struggling changing a CSS class attribute value of "float :left" to "float: none" for ages now.

I have a class in here:
[image]

I tired everything... I found the class in `http\app\design\frontend\Venustheme\cricket\web\css\source\_widgets.less`:

```
.owl-carousel{
    width: auto !important;
    margin-left: -(@grid-gutter-width/2)!important;
    margin-right: -(@grid-gutter-width/2)!important;
    .owl-item{
        padding-left: @grid-gutter-width/2!important;
        padding-right: @grid-gutter-width/2!important;
        float: left;
        .translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    }
    .owl-wrapper {
        .translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        float:left;
    }
    .owl-stage{float: left;}
    .owl-nav.disabled{display: none;}
}
```

Changed it to `float: none;` and did following:

> Flushed Static files Cache
>
> Flushed Javascript / CSS Cache
>
> Flushed Catalog Images Cache
>
> Flushed Magento Cache
>
> Flushed Storage Cache
>
> Flushed Cache using Magerun
>
> Purged Redis Cache
>
> Purged Varnish Cache
>
> Re-deployed static content
>
> Removed files from `rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/` and redeployed again.

Nothing... It's driving me insane now. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: did you change it inside the cricket theme or the cricket_child theme, because your screenshot shows you are using the cricket_child theme?

Comment: I have searched through the child theme directory and there is no signs of CSS class `.owl-stage` within the `app/design/frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/*`. I can only find the class in the parent theme directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a Suggesion , 
You can use child theme css, try to write css using page layout class and element to element, 
eg. checkout-cart-index {
.your-main-section { 
 .sub-section { 
  .owl-carousel {
   .owl-wrapper {
        float:left;
        } 
      }
   }
 } 
}